# Facebook JS SDK - How to post custom story to timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, timeline

I am trying to post a custom story to the user's timeline. When I try to post the story, it does not appear in the user's timeline, but it appears in the user's activity log (under the user's profile).

In order for the story to show in the timeline he has to select it in his activity log and choose "Show on timeline". Obviously this is not what I want. Is there any way I can make it show directly in the timeline?

I am using the following code:

```
var parent = this;
FB.api(
  'me/' + parent.facebook_app_namespace + ':score',
  'post',
  {
    newscore: "http://mydomain.com/open-graph/newscore?app_id=" + parent.facebook_app_id + "&game_id=" + parent.my_app_id + "&score=" + params.score + "&access_token=" + parent.facebook_app_access_token
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

The code returns a object id, which indicates that the story has been posted successfully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this is due to the fact that your app is in the **development** mode- in that case stories are not published on the wall but visible in the Activity Log.

You can switch your app to **live** mode in the App Settings-

[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks like the reason! I have created a test user and it shows in the test user's timeline. Many thanks!!